# Cross join 2 columns in pandas after splitting them in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling, data-preprocessing

I have two columns from a csv file :

[image]

I want to process them in such a way that they look like this

[image]

Notice that they arent comma(,) seperated.

I've tried a lot of things , but none of them have worked out. This has been holding up my work for quite a bit of time.

Grateful for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example data you should be able to achieve this using a combination of [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Countries": ["Fi kj jb hbh", "cdd jbh", "nfh"],
    "Groups": ["x1x2 xc jui", "wer", "ww3"]
})

output = (
    df
    .assign(
        Countries = lambda x: x["Countries"].str.split(" "),
        Groups = lambda x: x["Groups"].str.split(" ")
    )
    .explode("Countries")
    .explode("Groups")
)
```

This gives the following output:

| Countries | Groups |
| --- | --- |
| Fi | x1x2 |
| Fi | xc |
| Fi | jui |
| kj | x1x2 |
| kj | xc |
| kj | jui |
| jb | x1x2 |
| jb | xc |
| jb | jui |
| hbh | x1x2 |
| hbh | xc |
| hbh | jui |
| cdd | wer |
| jbh | wer |
| nfh | ww3 |